# Record remote video stream with audio using webrtc for Mac

Tags: webrtc, mp4, video-recording, peer, webrtc-ios

I need a way to record the audio and video of remote peer connections.
We're using the native version of webrtc for macOS.
In the current API of webrtc, there is no way to access the audio of remote connections.

I didn't try anything in particular because this is something that I can't find any reference for.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i can't specify more than what i've said. we can't identify audio devices from the remote connection using the native webRTC implementation for Mac OS., That should be enough for someone to help me out figuring this out. :)